# AWS Lambda nodejs mysql query inside loop is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  let index = 0;
    var client = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.rds_host,
      user: process.env.rds_username,
      password: process.env.rds_password,
      port: process.env.rds_port
    });
    client.connect((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });
  let array = [];
  let queries = ["query1", "query2", "query3", "query4"];
  queries.map(q => {
    array.push(getQueryResult(client, q));
  });
  Promise.all(array).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
  callback(null, {});
};

const getQueryResult = async (client, query) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.query(query, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
};
```

Above is my lambda scripts to execute multiple query from mysql. The problem is I didn't get any result and error message from above scripts. Please help me something is missing inside my scripts?

Comment: so on client.connect you ain't got the log "Connected! ?

Comment: @rags2riches Yap, I have not seen "Connected".

Comment: There are two possible issues here: 1) the if statement is not evaluated because you are using "undefined" whereas this is meant to be `undefined` as primitive type 2) you are not `await` the connection to the db

Comment: What is the purpose of evaluating the `typeof` client? client is not declared or assigned before the if so you **want it** to be undefined...why is the if necessary?

Comment: @rags2riches `undefined` means I don't want to open connection again as using existing connection. And in promises.all, we don't need to put `await` there.

Comment: just check that the connection to you mysql database is not open (it is closed) and if it is, you then connect and assign to the variable client. Checking the typeof client is **not** getting evaluated.

Comment: @rags2riches when I've changed like that, I've got another error `ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected`

Comment: you changed that to what? you are getting an Error which is good !

Comment: @rags2riches Please check my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two or three (potential) issues with your code above:

1. Your if statement does not get evaluated because of the `typeof` client predicate does not return true.
2. your `mysql` port conflicts with your `localhost` port (assumption)

Change your if block as such:

```
 // check if `dotenv` has been called if you use it
 require('dotenv').config();
 
 // access the state property on mysql object
 // if you have closed your connection previously
 // this will get evaluated by the parser
 if (mysql.state === "disconnected") {  
 
      var client = mysql.createConnection({
          host: process.env.rds_host,
          user: process.env.rds_username,
          password: process.env.rds_password,
          port: process.env.rds_port        // is your port the same as your localhost?
          // include your database name here
        });
     
      // I suggest you to await your client connection
      // since mysql executes sequentially, not asynchronously
      client.connect(function(err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
          }
          console.log("Connected!");
        });
 }
```

if the error persists, it means that your enviroment variables are not set correctly so your db configuration should be reviewed (see inline comments).

Answer (score 2):

**The issue is >>  code is not waiting to finish Promise**

You can resolve by :

**Add callback in then**

```
Promise.all(array).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    callback(null, {});
  });
```

OR

Use **await**

```
let result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
console.log(result)
callback(null, {});
```

Note: Use try-catch to handle error in for **await**

Also, don't use `map` to loop array instead use `For loop`.